# Socket proxy server redirecting url

Tags: java, sockets, proxy

I have a basic socket proxy server, I want to add redirection functionality in it. Any idea how do I go. Just changing the host doesn't help because the buffer that is collected from the client contains the old information.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SimpleProxyServer {

    public static final int portNumber = 5555;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleProxyServer proxyServer = new SimpleProxyServer();
        proxyServer.start();

    }

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Starting the SimpleProxyServer ...");
        try {

            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(
                    SimpleProxyServer.portNumber, 1);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];

            while (true) {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

                InputStream bis = clientSocket.getInputStream();


                int n = bis.read(buffer);
                String browserRequest = new String(buffer, 0, n);
                System.out.println(browserRequest);

                int start = browserRequest.indexOf("Host: ") + 6;
                int end = browserRequest.indexOf('\n', start);
                String host = browserRequest.substring(start, end - 1);
                System.out.println("Connecting to host " + host);


                Socket hostSocket = new Socket(host, 80); //I can change the host over here
                OutputStream sos = hostSocket.getOutputStream();
                System.out.println("Forwarding request to server");
                sos.write(buffer, 0, n);// but then the buffer that is fetched from the client remains same
                sos.flush();


                InputStream sis = hostSocket.getInputStream();
                OutputStream bos = clientSocket.getOutputStream();

                System.out.println("Forwarding request from server");

                do {
                    n = sis.read(buffer);
                    System.out.println("Receiving " + n + " bytes");
                    if (n > 0) {
                        bos.write(buffer, 0, n);
                    }
                } while (n > 0);

                bos.flush();
                hostSocket.close();
                clientSocket.close();
                System.out.println("End of communication");

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here my client is a browser, so the buffer contains lots of data.

Any example of browerRequest is

```
GET http://www.yahoo.com/ HTTP/1.0
Host: www.yahoo.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: close
Proxy-Connection: close
Cookie: B=c6r6cn99536pm&b=3&s=ha; fpc=d=mEdlILxMtEbSZkEHT9nArn_LmO6DBF2HC4aZWnYvepTQpHb86MidH7bPbylrLChwtcznc4rZnUWz5R_xvFr6WJYcYJnpG_aBqekaFtBKsmCUsblQQtM1ivZpRz7m6PYiQtwtcoGVAs55IhfOy0eaqXdfEif8ZkXrgpiYjmy2Qm_wkORpT5tXcZKJ.nKcMcUqh7aoTVA-&v=2; MSC=t=1381079862X; BILLBOARD=nv=1&bn=0&collapsed=0; ypcdb=e5e21a3dacf7b87ec358a08261d310ec
```

The next time when the while loop again iterates the browserReqest becomes,

```
GET http://in.yahoo.com/?p=us HTTP/1.0
Host: in.yahoo.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: close
Proxy-Connection: close
Cookie: B=c6r6cn99536pm&b=3&s=ha; MSC=t=1381079862X; fpc=d=NVQLQy5MtEYnypFx54.9vMbBB6hMzgZBTkPUzrh5pyN7MdDAbbwV96dq9xhvHLfj_A.DBwRKIwUiufAsj8Gs1EBtj3slZb31KrhNjPe5lEAgMlEeXUijTqpYZnFWROwAFjCqcd_4SV90e1XEu87kCBT7Lb1rzodBKY1ZUHmC57O0QEJWL8rJJcEcaODEc.69elh3CaiKmaxkP5rwWbx0FK15ZCCYbJROMwwFXovaYBfR.Re27s4saqnUCBQSFI3Ro80k_ci5&v=2; fpps=_page=%7B%22wsid%22%3A%2221445690%22%7D; fpt=d=DV0PgAXXeVzrfc2GezJLqQPfzZiyGbbBhDpW.vmTd6yHOqDQACyQiLPWz..0N0jUP35Yo9S9Yw8rMuXlE9gjZ1Ra3MhzyfnyMN67b_8cb7d7NbRceZS4AzDaVqbHB_9Tfyeznojpm3AuzqGUdfG2fnoMVl4OqKM_a7Mt3vV8U4Qr38gB864WFl6NXOyz7n_T1FA89lQfsWVob0oOzuXWNfieD_jikxauj.3nFDkbkFH6qATpBXHLGP7OvE7ibc0IL.66u7kDDaawvEOSSyh1tv3LhSrYshHS5MfslHpkSUJsP4lIBNxcQQRJWBmw27rl9mfg.R7vAOQwFHi6_24D0XtQDhKntlO2sWSCplscG35S353IBzPRZranUwp_fYP3XuePv6E8yAkENSCbmx5..vjQTLOMEEf5mUlNmFvQoxSRzlvoG5vAdRcPmELlbxs6MZxMd822gifvP063z9dF8lNRWZTcK8Mfq0ob4XSUplzWbbY6lb2yJIZ57ddogxHo6phfy59RqLqFPWSb38a9K3UU0TSjPDEg9wjfFmmdew--&v=1; fpc_s=d=2smDyqJMtEb.MYIbCNo48GeCPgKDD8rlRWYK4yILeDPeL8Rmu.M9oX3wGvweGpvAQBcYSlyjemeKTeHpqOmaDGC.eKT3dwzmsyUMo48OZJEkv2z_fkIIMkipQJsEMCFngcwJ8tJL_R2hZBS6Z3MjJwmD28zABdGjrhJ71RmXmfkj6Ofas8R4UkkcXvyGgVsyGKxOeYip45UMltDfVpBa7SNz_GAcrhtpvlV6PRjF4ffKxTpAdx5uGiXok_5S7UmGpD8iQR.SOkZ0uhAr3iBl6wpoVGIHvPvOqPaZ8pAJApGQwmp85Ul3uJYqpXanb0B.WxaiyUXr6DlQBzUVrXHcn0Pm5_pQ6yATqiq0jBzsQqZNDAC8JAqecLmgRQUa7E_7B60IsEwV7TIq1mDdNhDgIk5lbIncWwLYVmoUyPxI0.UYcPJW&v=2; FPCK2=AgBSUZsQABPEEABFMhAARIgQAGMC; BILLBOARD=nv=1&bn=0&collapsed=0; ypcdb=e5e21a3dacf7b87ec358a08261d310ec
```

I just want to redirect the request of www.yahoo.com to lets say www.google.com

How do I achieve this ? Because from what I can see is I cannot edit buffer that is received from the client/browser.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything about the content. The client will route the request for the embedded URLs in the same way that it routed the request for the URL you are currently proxying: to you.

Comment: I guess you dont get my question. I type www.yahoo.com in my browser. So a request for www.yahoo.com will come to the proxy, but I want my proxy to send the external server a request for www.google.com and send this response back to the browser. Hope things are more clear now.

Comment: so what you are trying to say is whatever URL you you type in the browser it has to be redirected to the page that you set. is it ?
for example if you set the proxy server to point to google.com so whenever the user types any URL the page has to be redirected to google.com ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but trying to solve this capturing the request/response by servlet. Try this http://www.tidytutorials.com/2009/12/simple-java-proxy-servlet-using.html and change the URL to redirect. Response is not thee best (images, css and js are not rendered) but by changing Content-type it can be resolved.